# App not working on two type of device

Tags: android

I have a serious problem with my android application. I tested it on every size of device and every type of API levels. I have uploaded my app to the Google Play and some of my friends told me that when they click on the start button they got an error message and the app closed. The message was recived on a Samsung Galaxy Alpha and a Galaxy S5. Could you please tell me some reason that an app which was tested thousand times on a dozen of devices why not working on these type of phones?

```
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  
        ComponentInfo{hu.szada.kepkirako/hu.szada.kepkirako.BSzintesActivity}: 
       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView at        

       android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2658)
       at 

       android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2723)
    at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at 
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1422)
    at 
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at 
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at 
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1:    Error inflating class android.widget.ScrollView
  at 
  android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
  at 
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
 at 
android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:689)
 at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:748)
 at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
 at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
 at 
 android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
 at 
 android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
 at 
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
 at 
 hu.szada.kepkirako.BSzintesActivity.onCreate(BSzintesActivity.java:849)
 at 
 android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6221)
  at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
 at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2611)
 ... 10 more
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
  at 
   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
   ... 22 more
   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while        trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack available
```

Comment: you should check the crash logs in your Google Play Developer Dashboard, or copy and paste it here so that we can know what is causing the error.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: `BSzintesActivity` is inflating a layout with a `ScrollView` at it's root. At the end of the stack trace I see a `OutOfMemoryException` so my guess is the ScrollView has a background, it's a bitmap and it's ridiculously suboptimal in size. Keep in mind that the .png may have a few kilobytes but before it can be shown on screen it is expanded to full 32 bit bitmap. If this is the case, please, post the image, we'll try to optimize it for Android.

Comment: Thank very much for you answer! I optimized it and the app is working now!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to implement a reporting system in your app so you can get reports when your app is crashing or not behaving correctly.
I personally use [ACRA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra), where i can silently save all crashes in my server so i can fix them. You can also get emailed every time your app gets crashed in any device and get the logcat so you can fix it.